# Is $\Bbb R$ definable in $(\Bbb C,0,1,+,*,\exp)$?

Tags: logic, model-theory, first-order-logic

Is there a first-order formula ϕ(x) with exactly one free variable $x$ in the language of fields together with the unary function symbol $\exp$ such that in the standard interpretation of this language in $\Bbb C$ (where $\exp$ is interpreted as the exponential function $x \mapsto e^x$), $ϕ(x)$ holds iff $x \in \Bbb R$?

My thoughts: If one takes the algebraic theory of the complex field without the exponential function, then $\Bbb R$ is not definable because there are isomorphisms of $\Bbb C$ mapping reals to non-real numbers. Does a similar approach work in this case? In particular, is there any other isomorphism of the exponential $\Bbb C$ structure besides the identity and complex conjugation?

Comment: At least one can get $\mathbb Q$:

$$z\in\mathbb Q\iff\exists a\colon\exp(a)=1\land a\ne 0\land \exp(za)=1$$
This is because this implies that $a$ and $za$ are both integer multiples of $2\pi i$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: Unfortunately, I don't see any possibility to extract topological information from \exp.

Comment: I think that this problem is equivalent to defining complex conjugation.  If you can, then you can define norm, which is always real; hence you can define $\mathbb{R}$.  And if you can't, then how do you distinguish $\mathbb{C}$ from its image under conjugation?

Comment: By the axiom of choice, there is an isomorphism of $(\Bbb C,0,1,+,\times,\exp)$ that does not fix the reals.

Comment: @GEdgar: Could you be a bit more explicit?

Comment: @Dominik: see this answer http://math.stackexchange.com/a/412034/442

Comment: That doesn't seem to include exp, as far as I can tell.

Comment: You are right, it does not include exp.

Comment: Maybe one could argument in this way: Let $pi$ be a real transcendental number, there are only countably many numbers standing in a nontrivial exponential-polynomial relation with $pi$. Thus there is a $z$ which is exponentially independent of $\pi$ and we map $\pi$ to $z$. Now hopefully some compactness argument may allow us to extend this to a whole $\Bbb C_{exp}$ isomorphism.

Comment: $x$ is real if and only if $\{ \exp(i n x) : n \in \mathbb Z\}$ is bounced.  Now $\mathbb Z$ is definable, but is boundedness?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is a major open problem in model theory. Recent attempts to study ${\mathbb C}_{\exp}$ have been centred around Zilber's pseudo-exponentiation, which is a nice structure and module some (very serious) algebraic conjectures coincides with ${\mathbb C}_{\exp}$. Zilber's pseudo-exponential field is quasiminimal (i.e. every definable set is countable or co-countable) and hence $\mathbb R$ is not definable there. Have a look at [Marker's paper](http://homepages.math.uic.edu/~marker/eac-fin.pdf) for an introduction.