# Can $\mathrm{Aut}(\Bbb C)$ be turned into a profinite group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, profinite-groups

It is known that for any (possibly infinite) Galois extension $L/K$, the Galois group is profinite, when endowed with the Krull topology (inherited from the inverse limit).

> Can $\mathrm{Aut}(\Bbb C)$ be endowed with a topology with respect to which it is a profinite group (i.e. compact, Hausdorff, totally disconnected)?

---

Some thoughts:

According to the answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/779242/is-there-a-nice-topology-on-autc), one might define a basis of open neighborhoods of the identity via $\{ \mathrm{Aut}(\Bbb C/K)  \mid  K \text{ finitely generated} \}$, and we obtain a topological group which is Hausdorff and totally disconnected. Is it correct? (The answer doesn't give any proof). If moreover it is locally compact, we could conclude that $\mathrm{Aut}(\Bbb C)$ is a locally profinite group.

But the answer above tells that this topological group is compact iff every $z \in \Bbb C$ has finite orbit. This is not the case, since $ \Bbb C \cong \overline{\Bbb Q(X_a : a \in \Bbb R)}$ and $X_a \mapsto X_{a+1}$ (for all $a \in \Bbb R$) extends to an automorphism of $\Bbb C$ with infinite orbit. However, the answer doesn't give any references, and this might not be the only topology that we may consider on $\mathrm{Aut}(\Bbb C)$ (of course, the discrete topology is totally disconnected and Hausdorff but not compact, while the trivial topology is compact but not Hausdorff).

Thank you!

Comment: My question came up because there is an extension $K$ of $\Bbb Q$ whose automorphism group [is $\Bbb Z$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1871485/), but such an extension [can't be](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2829467) algebraic. The issue being that in the second case we have a structure of profinite group (which $\Bbb Z$ [can't have](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/4939)).

Comment: Profinite groups are residually finite… would that help?

Comment: [NB : using the axiom of choice, $Aut(\Bbb C)$ has cardinality $2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$]

Comment: I don't think $|\operatorname{Aut}(\Bbb C)| = 2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$.