# Field automorphisms and fixed fields

Tags: field-theory

I currently have to cope with field automorphisms.
I already understood that any field automorphism of $\mathbb{C}$ must fix all elements in $\mathbb{Q}$.

My question is the following: Assume a number $x$ is fixed by every field automorphism of $\mathbb{C}$. Does that imply that $x \in \mathbb{Q}$?

My strong guess is that this implication is true but I could not come up with an idea for a proof. Any hint into the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: I think that this is not correct. I don't have a proof on hand, but I do know that there is no nontrivial automorphism of $\mathbb{R}$. This is a counterexample to your intuition.

Comment: Dear @AdamHughes : it does not appear the poster is assuming continuity... something would have to be said about that to make the comment follow?

Comment: But there are algebraic automorphism of the complex numbers that are non-continuous, which is what the question is about. @AdamHughes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out to be true. Since I don't think your question is a duplicate, but it is nicely addressed at [this solution by Andres Caicedo](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/412034/29335), I'm giving you a community wiki answer to point you to it.

If you take a look at the discussion right before the second to last paragraph, you can learn why exactly the rationals are fixed.