# What is the inverse of $g$?

Tags: functions

Define $A := \{(a,b) \in \mathbb{N}^2 \, \mid \, \gcd(a,b) = 1 \text{ and } 1 \le a < b\}$.

Does a bijection exist between $A$ and $\mathbb{N}$?

I tried the following map:

> Let $g: \mathbb{N} \to A$ such that
> $$\begin{equation*}
> g(n) =\left\{
>      \begin{array}{ll}
>            (1,n), \quad \text{iff } n = p^k, \text{ for some } 2 
> \le k \in \mathbb{Z}^{\ge 0} \text{ and } p \in \mathbb{N}\\
>            (a,b), \quad \text{iff } n \ne p^k \text{ for any } k \in \mathbb{Z}^{\ge 0} \text{ and } p \in \mathbb{N}, n = ab \text{ with largest factor } b>a, \text{ and } \gcd(a,b) = 1
>      \end{array}
> \right.
> \end{equation*}
> $$

For example, $g(28) = (4,7)$. Also, $g(100) = (1,100)$ because $10^2 = 100$.

**Questions:**

- What is the explicit inverse of $g$?
- Furthermore, can someone simplify the definition of $g$?
- Is $g$ a bijective map? I proved it, but I want to ensure that my map is "ok." If anyone wants to see the proof, let me know.

**Why am I interested in this?**

I want to make $A$ into a group with a well-defined operation $\star$. I used this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/995580/a-unique-operation-on-a-set-that-makes-it-a-group) for reference. However, it is not important to make $A$ into a group, but to make a bijection from $A$ to $\mathbb{N}$, because it's the only thing I am confused about from curiosity.

### Edit

Using the comments below, how about changing $g$ to

> $$\begin{equation*}
> g(n) =\left\{
>      \begin{array}{ll}
>            (1,n), \quad \text{iff } n = p^k, \text{ for some } 2 
> \le k \in \mathbb{Z}^{\ge 0} \text{ and } p \in \mathbb{N}\\
>            (a, \frac{n}{a}), \quad \text{iff } n \ne p^k \text{ for any } k \in \mathbb{Z}^{\ge 0} \text{ and } p \in \mathbb{N}, \gcd(a,\frac{a}{n}) = 1, \text{ and } a \in \min_{x \in \mathbb{N}} \{x \text { divides } n 
> \text{ and } x \ge 2\}
>      \end{array}
> \right.
> \end{equation*}
> $$

Comment: There's something wrong with your definition of $g$, unless you imply $p$ to be prime (which is not stated) or $k \ge 2$, since $n = p^1$ trivially for all $p \in \mathbb N$.

Comment: Why is that? Is it ambiguous if I don't state it?

Comment: Oh I see, I'll fix it!

Comment: You still have another problem with $g$:  for example, if $n = 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 7 = 105$, then we have three factorizations $n = 3 \cdot 35 = 7 \cdot 15 = 5 \cdot 21$, but $g$ cannot possibly map to all three of these.

Comment: But notice it says largest factor in the following sense: largest factor $d$ of $n$ such that $d < n$ means that if other $c \mid n$, then $c \le d$.

Comment: The question becomes, which of these three pairs $(3,35), (7,15), (5,21)$, all of which are obviously relatively prime, maps to $n = 105$?  There are no other possible choices for $n$.

Comment: However, I think I understand what you're saying.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138015/discussion-between-joshua-ortiz-and-heropup).

Comment: The set $A$ is countably infinite, so a bijection exists.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I fixed it.

Comment: A general observation is that a bijection $g$ cannot have the property that $n=ab$ whenever $g(n)=(a,b)$. This is because, using @heropup's example, $(3,35)$, $(7,15)$ and $(5,21)$ are all elements of $A$, so they cannot all be mapped to $105$ by the inverse function.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen how about in the edit?

Comment: My previous comment applies to the edited version of $g$ as is. It is impossible to find a bijection $g:\Bbb{N}\to A$ such that $g(n)=(a,b)$ implies $n=ab$.

Comment: I linked to this in chat but as it essentially answers the question, it bears repeating here:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7643/produce-an-explicit-bijection-between-rationals-and-naturals