# Find an operation so that it makes $D^{2}=\{z\in \mathbb{C}\mid |z|<1\}$ a group.

Tags: group-theory, complex-numbers, binary-operations

Let $D^{2}=\{z\in \mathbb{C}\mid |z|<1\}$. Find operation $\oplus: D^{2}\times D^{2}: \rightarrow D^{2}$ so that it makes $D^{2}$ a group.

I have already defined some operations but these don't verify associative property. For example, I defined $f(z)=\frac{z}{1+|z|}$ and I defined $z\oplus w:=f(f(z)+f(w))$, but they don't verify associative property.

Thanks, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Any element in $D^2$ can be written as $e^{ix}$. Define $f(x,y)=e^{i(x+y)}$. Maybe this would work. I didn't check the conditions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A unique operation on a set that makes it a group](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/995580/a-unique-operation-on-a-set-that-makes-it-a-group)

Answer (score 3):

Choose any bijection $f:D^2\to\mathbb R^2$ ([it may even be a diffeomorphism](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1025308)) and let
$$z\oplus w:=f^{-1}(f(z)+f(w)).$$