# Do complex roots always come in pairs?

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers

The [Complex Conjugate Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_conjugate_root_theorem) states that, given the polynomial $p(x)$ with real coefficients $p \in \mathbb{R}[p]$ and one of its roots being $a+bi \in \mathbb{C}$, its complex-conjugate pair $\overline {z}$ **must** be a root as well. We could also intuitively conclude that only by multiplying $(a+bi)$ with $(a-bi)$ will the imaginary parts be destroyed, allowing $p$ to be a real polynomial.

Following this line of reasoning, it shouldn't be necessary for complex roots of a **complex** polynomial to come in pairs. However, this premise was used in solving one of my school assignments.

Do complex roots always have to come in pairs, regardless of the field in which the polynomial was defined?

Comment: No, not necessarily. You can always factor a polynomial over $\mathbb{C}$ into the product of distinct factors: $p(z)=a(z-z_1)\cdots(z-z_n)$. These roots need not be paired.

Comment: The main words in the theorem are **real coefficients**

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Consider the polynomial $z-i$ . . .

---

It's good to remember the *reason* the complex conjugate theorem is true in the first place: the map $z\mapsto \overline{z}$ is an automorphism of the field $\mathbb{C}$, and fixes the subfield $\mathbb{R}$ (this is a fancy way of saying $\overline{r}=r$ if $r$ is real). Thus - defining the "conjugate" $\overline{p}$ of a polynomial (with coefficients in $\mathbb{C}$) to be the polynomial whose coefficients are the conjugates of the corresponding coefficients of $p$ - we have the following:

- If $p$ is *any* polynomial and $z$ is a root of $p$, then $\overline{z}$ is a root of $\overline{p}$.
- If the coefficients of $p$ are from $\mathbb{R}$, then $\overline{p}=p$.

This second fact is no longer true for polynomials with coefficients from outside $\mathbb{R}$!

Note that this generalizes in a natural way to:

> Suppose $F$ is any subfield of $\mathbb{C}$, $\varphi$ is a field automorphism of $\mathbb{C}$ which fixes $F$, and $p$ is a polynomial with coefficients from $F$. Then if $z$ is a root of $p$, so is $\varphi(z)$.

This is the (fine, "a") first step towards **Galois theory** . . .

Comment: By the way, lest anyone be too impressed with the "theorem" in my  answer: try thinking of *any* other automorphism of $\mathbb{C}$, besides conjugation! It is consistent with ZF (=set theory without the axiom of choice) that there are in fact *no* other nontrivial automorphisms of $\mathbb{C}$, and even with the axiom of choice, the automorphisms which do exist are "pathological"; see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/412010/wild-automorphisms-of-the-complex-numbers. However, we do care very much about the general question, "Understand the automorphisms of [big] which fix [small]."

Answer (score 9):

$(z-i)(z-2i)$ has two complex roots, $i$ and $2i$, but their conjugates are not roots.

Comment: The field in which the polynomial was given was not specified. Does this mean $p \in \mathbb{R}[p]$ by default?

Comment: @banananina I suspect that yes, in the assignment you mention, "coefficients in $\mathbb{R}$" was a default assumption (although one which perhaps ought to have been spelled out).

Comment: This polynomial doesn't even have real coefficients?