# Extending an automorphism of finite order of $A \subset \mathbb{C}$ to an automorphism of the same order

Tags: complex-numbers, field-theory

Let $A \subset \mathbb{C}$ be a subfield of $\mathbb{C}$.

According to a result of P.B. Yale, [Theorem 7](https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/upload_library/22/Ford/PaulBYale.pdf), 
any automorphism of $A$ can be extended to an automorphism of $\mathbb{C}$;
see also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/412010/wild-automorphisms-of-the-complex-L) (and its good comments and answers).

**My question:** If we know, in addition, that a given automorphism of $A$ is of finite order (for example, of order $2$, namely an involution),
is it possible to know that its extension to $\mathbb{C}$ is of the same order
(or at least also of finite order)?
Or is it hopeless, and the best we can obtain is 'just' that it has an extension to $\mathbb{C}$, probably of infinite order?

In other words, can we adjust Zorn's Lemma to guarantee a finite order extension? (I am afraid that the answer is no.. I hope I am wrong).

Thanks for any comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is usually not possible to extend a finite order automorphism of $A$ to an automorphism of $\mathbb{C}$ of finite order.  More precisely, it follows from the Artin-Schreier theorem that any nontrivial finite order automorphism of $\mathbb{C}$ has order $2$, maps $i$ to $-i$, and has a fixed field which is real closed.  So if an automorphism of $A$ has order greater than $2$, it cannot have any finite order extension to $\mathbb{C}$.  Even if an automorphism of $A$ has order $2$, it may not extend to a finite order automorphism of $\mathbb{C}$ (for instance, if $i\in A$ and the automorphism fixes $i$).

Comment: Please, can one tell when there is a chance to extend an involution $g$ of $A$ to an automorphism of $\mathbb{C}$ of finite order $m$?. If $i \in A$, is $g(i)^2=-1$ the only necessary condition? I guess there may exist additional necessary conditions, is it possible to find them? Perhaps this depends on more information we should have about $A$? (And what if $i \notin A$?).

Comment: I don't know a simple answer to that off the top of my head, but sending $i$ to $-i$ is not sufficient.  I suggest asking that as a new question.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and comment. (I will probably ask a new question, as you suggested).