# If a bijection extends continuously a finite order bijection, is it also of finite (same) order? A generalization

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

After asking [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2233257/if-a-bijection-extends-continuously-a-finite-order-bijection-is-it-also-of-fini), it would be nice to know if some generalized version of it is also valid:

**Firstly,** is the following claim true:
Let $M$ be a [uniform topological space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_space), $S$ a dense subset of $M$, 
and $f : S \to M$. If $f$ is uniformly continuous and $M$ is complete, then there exists a unique continuous extension of $f$ to $M$. Furthermore, this extension is uniformly continuous.

**Secondly,** if the above claim is true, then my question is:
If we know that actually $f:S \to S$ and $f$ is an automorphism of finite order $d$,
and if we also know that the unique continuous extension $F: M \to M$ is an automorphism, is it true that $F$ must be of order $d$?

(The idea to replace a metric space by a uniform space is thanks to
[the comments in this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/461741/spaces-with-the-property-uniformly-continuous-equals-continuous)).

Remark: I think that if the above claim is true, then the same argument as in  [the first answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2233257/if-a-bijection-extends-continuously-a-finite-order-bijection-is-it-also-of-fini) should also work here, so my question has a positive answer.

**Moreover,** in case my question has a positive answer,
is it possible to further generalize it (with $M$ a topological space, which is not necessarily uniform?).

Comment: It seems that wikipedia (almost) answers my question, in the section "Relations with the extension problem" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_continuity

Comment: For example, instead of uniform continuity one can impose the weaker condition of Cauchy continuity.