# Restrictions of $Gal(\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{Q})$ to a finite extension $\mathbb{K}$ of $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, extension-field, galois-extensions

I have a doubt. Let $\mathbb{K}$ be a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}$. May I infer that the number of distinct restrictions of $Gal(\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{Q})$ to $\mathbb{K}$ must be finite? If yes, why?

Comment: I find hard to understand what you **really** meant by "distinct restrictions". If you mean that the restricted automorphisms are different, then the obvious answer is yes, as there cannot be more than $\;[\Bbb K:\Bbb Q]\;$ different automorphisms (or embeddings into $\Bbb C\,$) *fixing* $\;\Bbb Q\;$ of $\;\Bbb K\;$ . But if you meant whether there are infinite different automorphisms on $\;Gal(\Bbb C/\Bbb Q)\;$ that restrict to the same finite automorphisms (embeddings) of $\;\Bbb K/\Bbb Q\;$ are different then...I don't know.

Comment: It is better to call the field automorphism group of $\mathbb C$ over $\mathbb Q$ something other than `Gal', maybe just `Aut', because (of course) this is not an algebraic extension, and Galois theory does not quite apply...

Comment: I'm asking whether there are infinite different automorphisms on $Gal(\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{Q})$ that restrict to the same finite automorphisms of $\mathbb{K}/\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: @DonAntonio What do you mean by the sentence the restricted automorphisms are different, then the obvious answer is yes, as there cannot be more than $[\mathbb{K}:\mathbb{Q}]$ different automorphisms fixing $\mathbb{Q}$ of $\mathbb{K}$? Could you be more precise, please? Do you mean $\sigma|_{\mathbb{K}}$, for $\sigma \in \mathbb{C}$?

Comment: The number of restricted automorphisms must be finite, of course. That's what I meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I am not mistaking the comments above, if I got it right, the question is: Given some $\varphi\in\mathrm{Aut}_{\mathbb{Q}}(\mathbb{K})$, are there inifinitely many $\psi\in\mathrm{Aut}(\mathbb{C})$ with $\psi\vert_{\mathbb{K}}=\varphi$?

The answer to this is yes, for example theorem 7 of [this paper](https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/upload_library/22/Ford/PaulBYale.pdf) (link is taken from [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/412010/wild-automorphisms-of-the-complex-numbers)) states:

> Every automorphism of a subfield of $\mathbb{C}$ may be extended to an automorphism of $\mathbb{C}$.

So, as $\mathbb{K}$ is finite over $\mathbb{Q}$, you might choose inifinitely many algebraically independent (over $\mathbb{K}$) elements $\alpha\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\mathbb{K}$, with minimal polynomials, say, $f_\alpha\in\mathbb{K}[x]$, and independently set each of them to arbitrary roots of the $\varphi(f_\alpha)$, to get inifinetly many different extensions to $\mathrm{Aut}(\mathbb{C})$ (which by construction restrict to $\varphi$ on $\mathbb{K}$).