# what is the action of $\operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb{Z})$ on $\mathbb{C}^n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-actions

Calculate the following actions:

$(i)$ Find an action of the group $GL(n,\mathbb{R})$ on the Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^n$.

$(ii)$ Find an action of the group $GL(n,\mathbb{C})$ on the Euclidean space $\mathbb{C}^n$.

$(iii)$ Find an action of the group $\operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb{Z})$ on the Euclidean space $\mathbb{C}^n$.

**Answer:**

$(i)$

Let $A \in GL(n, \mathbb{R})$ and $ v \in \mathbb{R}^n$, then the action is defined by $A \cdot v=Av$

i.e, the group act as a linear transformation.

$(ii)$

The similar action can be described in this case also.

$(iii)$

We know $ \operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb{Z})=\{1,-1\}$.

Also the automorphism group $Aut(G)$ acts on $G$ by $ \psi \cdot g=\psi(g), \ \ \psi \in Aut(G)$ and $g \in G$.

But I do not know what is the action of $\operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb{Z})$ on $\mathbb{C}^n$ .

Is it Frobenius action or something else?

Kindly explain and answer this part $(iii)$.

Comment: If you're simply asked to find *an* action, with no further specifications, I would just define the trivial action for all 3 groups and call it a day.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $\operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb Z)\simeq\{1,-1\}$, you can make it act on $\mathbb C^n$ by making $1$ act as $\operatorname{Id}$ and $-1$ act as $-\operatorname{Id}$, for instance.

Comment: Or as the identity and coordinatewise complex conjugation.

Comment: @Jose, If I change $Aut(\mathbb{Z})$ by $Aut(\mathbb{C})$, then what will happen?

Comment: Then you will get a new question. I suggest that you post it as such.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos, yes but I just want to know, how much change will happen. is it going to be difficult? why not just hints me at least?

Comment: I believe that it is difficult, due to the existenc of [wild automorphisms of $\mathbb C$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/412010/wild-automorphisms-of-the-complex-numbers).

Comment: @ArturoMagidin,  would  you  please explain "coordinate wise complex conjugation" ?

Comment: @M.A.SARKAR: Excuse me, but what is there to explain? If you do not follow that, then the gaps in your knowledge are too great for a comment to fix.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin, Yes I have little knowledge in Group Action, I am studying it now. Can you explain it shortly or refer me some notes or book ? I know any group acts on itself in two way, one is by left or right multiplication g→gh and another through conjugation g→ghg−1. Is this you are talking about ?   Or you are talking about the following: Let $V$ be a vector space over $\mathbb{C}$, then any antilinear map $\phi:V \to V$ satisfying $\phi^2=Id,$ $\phi(zv)=\bar z \phi(v), \ v \in V, \ z \in \mathbb{C}$ and $\phi(v_1+v_2)=\phi(v_1)+\phi(v_2)$ is the complex conjugation. Is it this?

Comment: @M.A.SARKAR Again, I can't teach you group actions on a comment. Go talk to your professor; they get paid to teach you.