# What is meant by $\text{coordinatewise complex conjugation}$ in group action?

Tags: group-actions

$\text{Group Action}:$

What is meant by $\text{coordinatewise complex conjugation}$ in group action ?

Do there there exists any concept of $\text{conjugation}$ in Group action ?

I am week in Group action theory.

This context is from my previous question on Group action here [what is the action of $\operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb{Z})$ on $\mathbb{C}^n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3256547/what-is-the-action-of-operatornameaut-mathbbz-on-mathbbcn), see the comment of @Arturo Magidin

Can someone explain it shortly  with an example?

Comment: You might want to give us the context where you encountered this statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Judging without context, I presume your have some vector $(c_1, c_2, \dots, c_n) \in \mathbb C^n$. In this case, the componentwise complex conjugation will be $(c_1^*, c_2^*, \cdots, c_n^*) \in \mathbb C^n$, since you are *conjugating* the *complex* vector *componentwise*.