# Ring homomorphism from $\Bbb R \to \Bbb C$ must be inclusion?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-homomorphism

I was wondering what are the ring homomorphism $f$ from $\Bbb R \to \Bbb C$ and to $\Bbb C \to \Bbb C$ ?

I think that there is only one ring homomorphism from $\Bbb R \to \Bbb C$ : the inclusion. I know that the only ring homomorphism from $\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ is the identity and I feel that the arguments used to prove it also works for the case of ring homomorphism  from $\Bbb R \to \Bbb C$.

For $\Bbb C \to \Bbb C$, the restriction to $\Bbb R$ is the inclusion if what I said previously is true. So maybe the identity is the only ring homomorphism from $\Bbb C \to \Bbb C$, but I struggle to show it and I feel that some complex analysis will be needed.

Comment: I bet you know another ring homomorphism $\Bbb C\to\Bbb C$. Think back to when you first were taught complex numbers. What's the first thing you learn that you can do to any complex number that's truly a new concept that you never learned about for real numbers? Also, finding _all_ the homomorphisms (of either type) gets into weird Axiom of Choice territory. How familiar are you with the AoC?

Comment: For the ring homomorphisms $\Bbb C\rightarrow \Bbb C$ see [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3915406/given-a-ring-homomorphism-f-mathbb-c-to-mathbb-c-prove-it-is-either-the-i).