# Why should we study morphism of $k$-schemes instead of morphisms of schemes?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

I have been self-studying algebraic geometry through youtube video lecture of Prof. Richard E. BORCHERDS. This is the link of the lecture that I have question about: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dvKfbXhNOB0&list=PL8yHsr3EFj50Un2NpfPySgXctRQK7CLG-&index=12.

He mentioned in the lecture that we prefer to study morphisms between two schemes (from $\text{spec}(\mathbb{k}) \to \mathbb{P}^n$ for example) viewing as schemes over $\text{spec}(\mathbb{k})$ rather than morphisms between themselves. To have morphisms between, say $\text{spec}(\mathbb{k}) \to \mathbb{P}^n$, we need to have an extra commutative diagram over $\text{spec}(\mathbb{k})$. Why should we prefer that? The professor mentioned that was because we want to avoid "weird" automorphism of $\mathbb{k}$. I couldn't understand what he was trying to explain by that. Could anyone explain this a bit more details? Some concrete example would be great. Thank you!

Comment: This is sort of like asking why, when we study vector spaces over a field $K$, we focus on $K$-linear maps between them instead of arbitrary additive maps between them.  Which do you think is the source of more interesting mathematics: the $\mathbf R$-linear maps $\mathbf R^m \to \mathbf R^n$ or all additive ($\mathbf Z$-linear) maps $\mathbf R^m \to \mathbf R^n$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How big is $\operatorname{Aut}(\operatorname{Spec} \Bbb C)$? Well, it depends what type of maps you consider. If you consider $\Bbb C$-algebra maps, then the unique automorphism is the identity. If you consider $\Bbb R$-algebra maps, then there are two automorphisms: the identity and complex conjugation. If you consider general ring maps, there are [at least $2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$ automorphisms](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/412010/wild-automorphisms-of-the-complex-numbers): pick a transcendence basis for $\Bbb C$ over $\Bbb Q$, and permute the transcendence basis. That's too many automorphisms, in that it doesn't correspond to the geometric picture we want - if we're trying to generalize classical algebraic geometry, a single (closed, reduced) point shouldn't have any automorphisms.

Answer (score -1):

**Question:** "Why should we prefer that? The professor mentioned that was because we want to avoid "weird" automorphism of k. I couldn't understand what he was trying to explain by that. Could anyone explain this a bit more details? Some concrete example would be great. Thank you!"

**Answer:** Any pair of schemes $X,Y$ have canonical maps to $S:=Spec(\mathbb{Z})$ and any map
$f: X\rightarrow Y$ is defined over $S$. Hence you may view an arbitry map of schemes as maps over the integers $\mathbb{Z}$. When working over a field $k$ you change your base scheme $S$ to $T:=Spec(k)$. There is a canonical map $\phi: \mathbb{Z}\rightarrow k$ mapping $\phi(m)=\phi(1+ \cdots + 1)=m\phi(1)=m\in k$. Hence the map $X \rightarrow S$ factors canonically as $X \rightarrow T \rightarrow S$. Hence when you are not working over a field $k$ you are working over $\mathbb{Z}$.

**Example 1:** If $k:=\mathbb{Q} \subseteq K:=\mathbb{Q}(i)$ you may look at two groups:

$$End_k(K)\text{ and }End_K(K).$$

Since $dim_k(K)=2$ it follows $End_k(K)=Mat(2,k)$ is the ring of $2\times 2$-matrices with coefficients in $k$ and $End_K(K)\cong K\cong k^2$. Hence when you change base field the situation changes.

**Example 2:** A map $\phi^*: Spec(K) \rightarrow Spec(K)$ defined over $k$
is given by an automorphism $\phi \in G(K/k)$ and there is only one map defined over $K$ - the identity map. The Galois group $G(K/k)$ enters in various formulas in algebraic number theory and arithmetic geometry, and when you change the base field, the set of morphisms changes and this relates to the Galois group.

**Example 3:** If $V\cong \mathbb{k}^{n+1}$ is a vector space over a field $k:=\mathbb{k}$, it follows there is a 1-1 correspondence between maps (over $k$)

$$ x: Spec(k) \rightarrow \mathbb{P}(V^*)$$

and lines $l_{x} \subseteq V$. Hence the $k$-rational points $x \in \mathbb{P}(V^*)(k)$ correspond 1-1 to lines $l_x \subseteq V$. This reflects the fact that projective space $\mathbb{P}(V^*)$ is a parameter space - it parametrize lines in $V$.