# status of the complex conjugation in the complex arithmetic

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-numbers

I am learning abstract algebra now, and get quite confused with many naive things.

A particular question is, what status does the complex conjugation have in the complex field? It is used very often in all problems. But is it a canonical or unique in some sense?

Geometrically, it is quite arbitrary---Just a reflection about the real axis. But we can also reflect about other axes, with arbitrary angles with the real axis.

Answer (score 1):

One point is that for a polynomial $f(x)$ with real coefficients, if $z\in\Bbb C$ is a zero, then the complex conjugate $\bar z$ is also a zero, since complex conjugation is a field automorphism leaving the real numbers fixed.

Comment: Indeed, complex conjugation is the only field automorphism of $\Bbb{C}$, other than the identity map.

Comment: @TheoBendit That's actually very false if one assumes the axiom of choice. There are infinitely many so-called [wild automorphisms](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/412010/wild-automorphisms-of-the-complex-numbers) of $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: @ViktorVaughn Oh, I thought I saw a proof of that once. I must be mistaken. Perhaps it was the only automorphism that left $\Bbb{R}$ fixed?

Comment: @TheoBendit Yes, since $\operatorname{Gal}(\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{R})$ has order $2$. The identity and complex conjugation are also the only continuous automorphisms.