# Automorphism-killing subset of the complex numbers closed under both addition and multiplication

Tags: complex-numbers, automorphism-group

It is well known that there are [wild automorphisms of the complex numbers,](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/412010/wild-automorphisms-of-the-complex-numbers) and that defining the topology on the complex numbers gets rid of all these wild automorphisms. Using this fact, I proved that any nontrivial automorphism of the field of complex numbers does not preserve the set of complex numbers with positive imaginary part, a set closed under addition (By "preserve" a subset I mean that the image of the subset under the automorphism should be the subset itself). I also proved that any nontrivial automorphism of the field of complex numbers does not preserve the set of complex numbers that is a semicircular arc with radius $0.5$ combined with a filled circle of radius $0.25$ centered at the origin, a set closed under multiplication.

My question: is there any such automorphism-killing subset of the complex numbers that is closed under **both** addition and multiplication?

Comment: Well, $\mathbb{C}$ is such a subset, so probably you need an assumption excluding that case.

Comment: @radekzak I do not mean "preserves each element of the subset." I mean that each element of the subset should map to an element of the subset, and each element outside the subset should map to an element outside the subset. I edited my question to clarify what I mean.